# Could anyone destroy human spoken, and written language?

Tags: historical-linguistics, sociolinguistics

I believe that there are or have been people/systems who believe in eradicating one specific language or sets of languages through suppression of its usage and removal of native speakers from their native linguistic contexts - like what was done with indigenous languages in the Americas.

I also believe there is a possibility for regimes wanting to control language, something 1984-style, but it makes no sense to completely eliminate language because there is still a need for communication and communication is itself one of the tools such a regime can use to exercise power. The degree to which this sort of control over language can effectively happen and what consequences it has for the speakers can be discussed, but in any case, a language would still exist.

So unless humans are biologically unable to produce language anymore I don't see how it could be destroyed.

What do you all think?

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for [worldbuilding.se].

Answer (score 4):

Sure. If you kill all the humans, there will be no more human language. But that's probably not what you're wondering. So let's assume this regime isn't willing to completely eradicate the human race in their quest to rid the world of language.

At this point, all the evidence suggests that humans are *really good* at finding ways to communicate. Some linguists attribute this to a "universal grammar" that's built in to the human brain and underlies all languages; others say that our brains are just very good at certain types of pattern recognition and processing. But the observable end result is the same: humans will find ways to communicate, and generally use similar mechanisms to communicate, no matter what obstacles you put in their way.

For example, if children are raised hearing a pidgin (an ad hoc mix of languages used for rudimentary communication), they'll extend that mixture, slowly come up with a more thorough grammar, and turn it into a full-fledged language. This is how creoles happen. Or if deaf children are raised with no access to sign language, they'll still find ways to communicate concepts to each other, which can result, again, in a full-fledged language system. Nicaraguan Sign Language (ISN) is the famous example for this one.

Whenever people need to communicate, they'll find ways to do so, and linguists have observed certain commonalities between all the different ways humans come up with to communicate—which might go back to our biology or might just be fundamentally the best way to convey information about the world (e.g. all languages combine entities with predicates in some way). This strongly suggests that language could arise again even if every trace of modern languages disappeared overnight. Unless you completely remove the need or the ability to communicate with other people, humans will find a way.